# Pass object's info to another activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, object, arraylist

I have a ListView that is populated with objects from an ArrayList.

When one of the items on the ListView is clicked, a new activity "Contact Info" is opened and displays the details of that contact.

I have a button "Edit" that when clicked, opens a new activity.

I want to fill the contact info with the info from the "Contact Info" activity.

I was able to do it with the onItemClick but I don't know how to do it using the button onClick.

Contacts.java:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UerdA.jpg

ContactInfo.java:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/me7Bq.jpg

Edit:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuCVT.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Use an `Intent` object, and use `.putExtra()` to put extra data on the intent.

When you are in the second activity, get the intent that started the activity with `.getIntent()`, and then use `.getStringExtra()` or any other data type you are using.

## Example:

#### Putting extra data in Intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, ContactInfoActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID", sessionId);
startActivity(intent);
```

#### Retrieving data from Intent

```
String sessionId= getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID");
```

Comment: I was able to do that to pass information of the object to the contactinfo.java from the contacts.java using that on the onItemClick. But I don't know how to pass that info and the id to the ContactInfo.java using the onClick

Comment: @PedroPinheiro are you trying to ask a question or just saying that it worked? I dont understand the gist of your comment.

Comment: Sorry. It didn't work. I sent the information from the Contacts activity using putExtra(EXTRA_CONTACTNO, (int)id.
On the second activity, I received it using (Integer)getIntent().getExtras().get(EXTRA_CONTACTNO).
Now I'm trying to send that information to a third activity but using the onClick method on a button and it doesn't let me put the (int) id

Comment: @PedroPinheiro What exactly did not work? I need more information if you want me to help you.

Comment: I was able to fix it. I posted the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it.

I just had to add: int contactNo = (Integer)getIntent().getExtras().get(EXTRA_CONTACTNO);
inside the onCLick.

Thanks

Comment: You can use `getIntExtra()` instead of `get()` and casting to `Integer`, that way you dont need to use casting.